# How do I make a full screen form in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx-2

**How do I make a full screen form in Java FX?**
That should look like game window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Stage.setFullScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen%28boolean%29).